# How to change hard coded limit of 50 transactional emails?

Tags: email

I'm sure I read recently that it was possible to change the maximum number of emails that can be sent using the transactional mail in CiviCRM. Did I imagine this or can the hard coded limit of 50 be set to another value?

Comment: I am not sure where you can change the limit of sending 50 transactional emails in one go....but I would like to warn you that if you change that limit the chances of getting blacklisted will increase!

Answer (score 16):

It's recommended to **use CiviMail for larger mailouts**. It's worth understanding the potential consequences of using "simple CiviCRM mail" to do mails in bulk; eg:

- Harming your own site's spam reputation by sending many emails without spam compliant unsubscribe links.
- Harming CiviCRM platform email reputation by using CiviCRM without respect to spam compliance.
- Timeouts and performance issues when trying to deliver large numbers of emails in a single request.
- ... ?

So, this has long been hard-coded in an attempt to avoid people changing it. **The limit is no longer hard-coded**; it's become a hidden setting: `simple_mail_limit`. You should be able to change this setting from the default either by using the CLI tool `cv`:

```
cv api setting.create simple_mail_limit=99
```

Or by adding a setting override in `civicrm.settings.php`:

```
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['other']['simple_mail_limit'] = 99;
```

See [configuring hidden settings in CiviCRM](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/customize/settings/#hidden-settings) for more info, and do take note of advice here to reflect on *why* you think you need to change this value!

Comment: I highly recommend understanding *why* this isn't a setting exposed for easy configuration; good starting points may be [CRM-20905: Simple mail : Make max emails a hidden config instead of hardcoded value set to 50](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20905), [PR discussion #10693](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10693) (Not sure if the extension mentioned here to expose the setting as UI exists?) and [PR discussion #10705](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10705)

Comment: Many thanks for your response(s). I fully understand the rationale and consequences. However I have one user who needs to send to a small group of a little over 50 contacts and I need to humour him! Now that we are using Mosaico there is no real difference to send using the bulk or transactional email. Given your response I am now able to make up my own mind about the way that we approach this.

Comment: Great! And yeah, I agree this may fit *your* situation well - this is a community resource and I'm also writing with future readers in mind who might not recognise the difference between using CiviCRM's direct and bulk mail systems if the warnings aren't clear :D If this response was helpful, please remember to [mark the answer accepted](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) - this will help future people in your situation to resolve the same!