# Email Send Now (to 50 or Less) - More than 50?

Tags: civievent, civimail

Is it possible to use email send now to more than 50 people?

Comment: yes you can. and i thought it was in civicrm.settings.php but i checked on the one site i know we have it set and didn't see it in there.

Comment: I remember this too but it was added [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10705/files#diff-bb0f435c587b76bb8f907df1d0d1f744) as a UI setting but I can't find it. Was it removed later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change hard coded limit of 50 transactional emails?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21073/how-to-change-hard-coded-limit-of-50-transactional-emails)

Comment: See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21073/how-to-change-hard-coded-limit-of-50-transactional-emails. It's a hidden setting because there's concern about misunderstandings. See that answer for how to set it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a hidden setting and can be set in below ways

1. Add below line in civicrm.settings.php

   $civicrm_setting['Mailing Preferences']['simple_mail_limit'] = '100';
2. Via drush or cv

   cv api Setting.create simple_mail_limit=100

   drush cvapi Setting.create simple_mail_limit=60
3. Mysql statement

   UPDATE civicrm_setting
   SET value = '100'
   WHERE name = 'simple_mail_limit';
4. Via api explorer
   [image]

Comment: oh - it can be done in code or in db. no wonder i was confused looking for it earlier.